# Android system app running but is not in the ActivityManager.getRunningTasks list

Tags: android

I have a system app running on the phone, it has 2 services and 1 activity, I can see it when I issue a `ps` command through ADB shell, yet it does not appear in the running applications list, neither in the ActivityManager.getRunningTasks list.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The activity would have been backgrounded. If you are looking though the running applications list, tap the "show cached processes" button to show the backgrounded activities.

as for getRunningTast list, make sure you have the apprioriate permissions. From the google docs:

> Note that "running" does not mean any of the task's code is currently
>   loaded or activity -- the task may have been frozen by the system, so
>   that it can be restarted in its previous state when next brought to
>   the foreground.

As for a solution, you would have to use another method/way to see if the activity is backgrounded or not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say "does not appear in the running applications list", you mean that it doesn't appear in the list of applications that are shown when you hold down the HOME key. This isn't actually a list of running applications. This is the "list of recently used applications".

It is possible to intentionally exclude an application from this list. The developers simply add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to the `<activity>` tag of the root activity in the Android manifest. This is an easy way to **hide** an application.

Comment: By the "running applications list" I meant the list of applications which can be found in the `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> Running`. I expect that this list contains the actually running applications. And yes, I know 100% that the application is not backgrounded, it is actively responding to requests and sending data. As I mentioned the ps list and top also show it as running & is a foreground application.

Comment: Also, if I call the `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks` ( I have the appropriate permission ), then I get other running system applications, only my app is not in it :\